# Mozart Ozcar Debugger Error

Tags: debugging, oz, mozart

So im studying, and i need to run Ozcar debugger including on Mozart, i go to Oz menu and first i pick feed buffer, after that i pick Start Debugger, the compiler show me the next message:

```
local A B in
   A = 5
   B = 6
   {Browse A+B}
end
% -------------------- accepted
\localSwitches
\switch +threadedqueries -verbose -expression -runwithdebugger
{Ozcar.open}
% -------------------- accepted
```

And then it suppose that a auxiliary windows should appears but nothing happens!!!! I need help pls!!!

Also the Oz emulator show me this:

```
%********************** Error: module manager *******************
%**
%** Could not link module
%**
%** Could not load functor at URL: x-oz://system/Ozcar.ozf
%**--------------------------------------------------------------
```

I think that the packagge of Ozcar is missing, where i can find it or how i can solve this???

Comment: Which version of Oz are you using? Normally, the debugger is contained in the default installation, at least in version 1.4.0.

Comment: Im unsing mozart2-2.0.0 that is in sourceforge

Comment: You should probably try 1.4.0 (also on sourceforge: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mozart-oz/files/v1/ ) I'm not involved with the development of Mozart, but maybe the debugger does not yet work in mozart2.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Mozart 1.4.0, the latest version of the 1.x Mozart branch.

Even if this question is more than 3 years old, the development of Mozart 2 is really slow and there still are a lot of features missing.